# Codeigniter succes or error

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('home');
    $this->load->model('reg', 'reg');
    $reg = $this->reg->getItems();
    $data['reg'] = $reg;
}

public function error()
{
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('username', 'Lietotājvārds', 'is_unique[reg.username]', 'alpha');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('fname', 'Vārds', 'required', 'greater_than[3]');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('lname', 'Uzvārds', 'required', 'alpha_dash', 'valid_email');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('pw', 'Parole' , 'required');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('pw2', 'Atkārtotā Parole' , 'required');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email', 'Emails' , 'required', 'valid_email');
    $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('email2', 'Atkārtotais Emails' , 'required', 'valid_email');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '{field} &#x1F60C; Opā Kāda kļūda.');
    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $reg['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
        $reg['fname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
        $reg['lname'] = $this->input->post('lname');
        $reg['pw'] = $this->input->post('pw');
        $reg['pw2'] = $this->input->post('pw2');
        $reg['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $reg['email2'] = $this->input->post('email2');
        $this->load->model('reg');
        $this -> reg -> saveItem($reg);
    }
    $this->reg_susses();
}
```

How can i make error message. And succest message. ?? 
 1. I go register hes give me the error in the same page us Succest page.
 2. when i success register hes give me the succest mesage in second page.
 3. i have 1 model = reg.php 
 4. i have 1 constroler = home.php
 5. 1 have 2 view = 1. reg.php 2. = reg_susses.php

Answer (score 1):

First, don't call your save method as **error**, it's misleading.

When you save, and the form validation passing, you can redirect the user to the success page:

```
public function save()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Lietotājvārds', 'is_unique[reg.username]', 'alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'Vārds', 'required', 'greater_than[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Uzvārds', 'required', 'alpha_dash', 'valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pw', 'Parole', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pw2', 'Atkārtotā Parole', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Emails', 'required', 'valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email2', 'Atkārtotais Emails', 'required', 'valid_email');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '{field} &#x1F60C; Opā Kāda kļūda.');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $reg['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
        $reg['fname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
        $reg['lname'] = $this->input->post('lname');
        $reg['pw'] = $this->input->post('pw');
        $reg['pw2'] = $this->input->post('pw2');
        $reg['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $reg['email2'] = $this->input->post('email2');
        $this->load->model('reg');
        $this->reg->saveItem($reg);

        // Redirect the user to the success page
        redirect('home/success');
    }

    // If it fails, it will reach this point, so we can load back our view
    $this->load->view('home');
}

// This is the success page
public function success()
{
    $this->load->view('success_page');
}
```

In your view, you can display error messages like this:

```
<div>
<?php echo validation_errors() ?>
</div>
```